# Влияет ли тип и производитель сертификата SSL на скорость соединения?

Tags: ssl, handshake

Влияет ли тип сертификата (DV, EV) и кто его выдал на скорость соединения?

Особенно интересует момент обращения к сертификационному центру в процессе рукопожатия (handshake). Имеют ли более дорогие сертификаты или сертификаты с расширенной проверкой приоритет на соединение или это никак не влияет на скорость?

Comment: лишние обращение к "сертификационному центру" замедляют работу.  Также замедляют работу длинные цепочки доверенных сертификатов (если нет вложенных корневых). Также может влиять размер ключа (дольше проверять). Цена сертификата влияет в основном на ЧСВ.

Comment: А разве идет обращение к сертификационному центру во время рукопожатия? Идет проверка на доверенный сертификат в локальном хранилище доверенных сертификатов. К центру обращаются разве что за revocation list.

Comment: Во время хендшейка можно обратить внимание на размер сертификата. Чем больше в нем информации, тем он больше весит. Если Вы уже знаете, что хендшейк - то самое место, которое тормозит работу, то вопрос может быть актуален. У вас есть такие замеры производительности, допустим, хотя бы на паре тысяч одновременных соединений к Вашему серверу (было бы интересно взглянуть на статистику: чтобы был выделен хендшейк и хотя бы одна полезная функция сервера, чтобы их можно было сопоставить - оценить затраты)?

Comment: @mega в том то и дело, что таких данных нет) интересно, может кто-то уже делал подобные тесты, какие были результаты производительности. эту проблему отчасти решает OCSP Stapling, но при первом обращении все равно идет запрос к удостоверяющему центру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @mega в том то и дело, что таких данных нет) интересно, может кто-то уже делал подобные тесты, какие были результаты производительности. эту проблему отчасти решает OCSP Stapling, но при первом обращении все равно идет запрос к удостоверяющему центру.

Раз таких данных нет, то могу Вас заверить, что на современных ОС тип сертификата не может существенно влиять на скорость соединения клиента с Вашим сервером.

Чтобы появилось такое влияние, надо по крайней мере отключить кеширование SSL сессий на стороне клиента или сервера (которое криптопровайдеры обычно включают по-умолчанию).

При включенном кешировании, после первого хендшейка, на протяжении нескольких часов (10 на последних версиях windows) либо пока не будут завершены процессы клиента/сервера, между 2мя хостами работает **"укороченный хендшейк"**, в котором сертификат и ключ не посылаются вообще, т.к. используется `master secret`, сгенерированный сессией-инициатором (первой сессией, которая провела полноценный хендшейк).

```
The client sends a ClientHello using the Session ID of the session to
be resumed. The server then checks its session cache for a match.  If
a match is found, and the server is willing to re-establish the
connection under the specified session state, it will send a
ServerHello with the same Session ID value. At this point, both
client and server must send change cipher spec messages and proceed
directly to finished messages. Once the re-establishment is complete,
the client and server may begin to exchange application layer data.
```

Соответственно, влияние типа или размера сертификата на скорость соединения может проявиться только в том случае, если география подключений к Вашему серверу достаточно разнообразна (много unique visitor), либо Ваш сервер реализует какую-то основную функцию с одним запросом: допустим, клиент имеет список Ваших типичных серверов (распределенных по сети), которые он выборочно опрашивает с очень небольшой периодичностью.

---

Подробности по кешированию сессий можно узнать в rfc на любой современный протокол TLS ([rfc2246#appendix-F.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#appendix-F.1.4) для tlsv1.0, например).

У Microsoft можно посмотреть статью [How to configure Secure Sockets Layer server and Client cache elements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/247658/how-to-configure-secure-sockets-layer-server-and-client-cache-elements) для получения дополнительных сведений по настройкам кеширования клиента/сервера в разных версиях windows.